# Verify email address is exist or not on IPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios4

My  problem isn't validating an email address. I want to verify that an email address exists or not.
I have been looking solutions for that all day. But no result is useful to me.
Can any one help me with this? Thanks!
Ge.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so trivial, but there are a number of options:

1) Find out, using DNS lookups, which mail servers are responsible for the domain of the E-Mail address and connect to one of them. Using SMTP try to deliver a message to the target address. Some servers will tell you at that point that the target address does not exist.

2) Send a test mail to the target address and check if you get a bounce/error mail back.

Comment: Thank you badcat, do you know any sdk or tutorial support it?

Answer (score 0):

Not trivial, as badcat already said. If you absolutely have to, I would some other entity do the actual work of sending and receiving the email (such as your webserver). The flow would be something like

1) your app instructs your webserver to send a testing email (make sure you secure this - else it will be perfect for spamming)

2) your app instructs the user that a test email has been sent and that he should reply to it, confirming he's a human (or maybe click on a url contained in the email)

3) the users response (click on url or email reply) will be recorded in a small DB which you can query with your app